# Exception message size for display in c#?

Tags: c#, exception

I have to output to another system a file with `Exceptions` and the other system only accepts a single line exception and its more like a reporting where we need a short description of the message.

I was planning to display only `Exception.Message`  to the output , but log `Exception.ToString` for logging.

Will the size of Exception Message be always 1 line? is there an alternate way to display these error messages which always be on a single line?

Also my assumption is that `Exception.ToString` contains `StackTrace` too ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Exception.Message` is a `string`. As such, **there is absolutely no guarantee of any sort that it will always hold onto a single line**. Most basic exceptions messages will, some won't, and with custom exceptions expect anything.

If one-line, short descriptions are absolutely necessary then you might want to consider using `Substring` and `Replace` to fit these requirements:

```
var maxLength = 50; // set to desired value
var strippedMessage = exception.Message;

strippedMessage = strippedMessage.Replace("\n", string.Empty); // removes newline char
strippedMessage = strippedMessage.Replace("\r", string.Empty); // removes carriage return char

if (strippedMessage.Length > maxLength)
    strippedMessage = strippedMessage.Substring(0, maxLength - 3) + "..."; // reduces the message's size
```

The three extra dots will give you a clue about the message having been stripped down. Needless to say, some relevant information may be lost here.

You should also know that often `InnerException` (if not null) is more relevant than the `Exception` instance. So if your "short message" is meant to give you a quick clue of what the real problem is, you may want to check for that instead.

Also **yes,** `ToString` **will *normally* contains** `StackTrace` **too**, as well as the nested inner exceptions `ToString` results. I say *normally* because the `ToString` method is overridable, so there's the slight possibility that some developer who felt creative decided to override it on a custom exception with something completely different.

Comment: @Crono.. I liked that idea of "...". Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Since `Message` is a string, there's no guarantee it won't contain newline characters (or any other characters that can normally be stored in a string).

---

Yes, `ToString()` includes the `StackTrace`. Actually, you get quite a bit more:

- the class name
- the `Message`
- the result of calling `ToString` on the `InnerException` *(which is itself an Exception, and includes everything in this list recursively)*
- finally, the `StackTrace`

Comment: It's worth mentionning that since ToString is overridable then it might return something completely unexpected, though. This is marginal but still something to think about for anyone making an exception reporting system.

Comment: It appears you are right, StackTrace *is* overridable. I didn't knew that. Wow. That's bad. :p

Answer (score 4):

If you are not sure whether a string is on a single line or not, replace the line breaks by spaces for instance

```
string msg = exception.Message.Replace("\r\n", " ");
```

My guess is that `exception.Message` will always be on a single line. But there is no guarantee. `Exception.ToString()`, however, will always be a multiline string that contains the stack trace.

Comment: instead of ´\r\n´ you could also use `Environment.NewLine`

Answer (score 3):

If the exception has an InnerException then you should add it's message info... and that exception may have an InnerException and so on.

The .ToString() is good to know **Where** the error occurred in code but the chained Messages are valuable.

Answer (score 3):

Since you can throw an exception with any string as the message, there is no guarantee that it will only be one line. However, you can replace the new lines in the string.

```
string message = e.Message.Replace( "\n", " " ).Replace( "\r", "" );
```